# Do any of the Hindu Scriptures have any perspective on loneliness and/or how to deal with mental health in general?

Tags: scripture, vedanta, health

I've lately been feeling quite lonely, due to - at least what I feel is a lack of - deep/meaningful connection. I am not sure where this sudden desire for community/friendship came from. I'm a university student and I didn't really have a group of friends for many years but suddenly I am feeling quite sad and moping around.

I'm trying to put myself out there and have what one may consider "friends" but all of these connections feel superficial. I don't have much connection to family as I live in the United States and they're in India. I've done daily sandhyāvandanā for years and it has always helped me feel better dealing with various issues (mostly academic / physical in nature) but even my daily prayers are not giving me comfort now.

As someone spiritually inclined, this is quite bothering to me, and I am not able to either focus on my academic pursuits, or my spiritual pursuits. I'm always thinking of one or another person, over analyzing why I might not be getting text responses, etc. etc. A verse from the subrahmanya bhujangam composed by Adi Shankaracharya comes to mind here:

> अहं सर्वदा दुःखभारावसन्नो 
> भवान्दीनबन्धुस्त्वदन्यं न याचे । 
> भवद्भक्तिरोधं सदा क्ऌप्तबाधं 
> ममाधिं द्रुतं नाशयोमासुत त्वम् ||

> *Aham Sarvadaa Duhkha-Bhaara-Avasanno 
>
> Bhavaan-Diina-Bandhus-Tvad-Anyam Na Yaace | 
>
> Bhavad-Bhakti-Rodham Sadaa Klpta-Baadham 
>
> Mama-[A]adhim Drutam Naashayo[a-U]maa-Suta Tvam ||*

> I am always sunken with the burden of Sorrows,
> You are the Friend of the Miserable in all the Worlds; apart from You, I Pray to None Else,
> Preventing full Devotion towards You by always causing Obstacles ...
> are my Mental Sorrows; O the Son of Uma, please Destroy them Quickly.

Would appreciate any perspective at all. Thank you.

Comment: Hey Nikhil, no probs and you will figure this out :) so, did you try googling your mental health issues and see what comes up ? Psych issues will be very different from spiritual issues, in my experience. Hinduism is highest knowledge and I love it more than anything, at the same time I think western psychology can sometimes be pretty good in helping folks with mental health. If you google psychology articles on your exact issues (try typing in questions many different ways, different keywords) lots of stuff comes up, mental health podcasts, youtube videos, posted questions on quora etc

Comment: Hey, thanks for your comment. I have asked to talk with a counselor through my university and I'm actively searching for other remedies. But I was hoping that this community might be able to give some insight into a religious perspective - as I'm more sure that I might more readily take to something that has been suggested by those scriptures that I respect :).

Comment: Sounds good, hopefully someone w/ scriptural knowledge will post proper answer below. Mods might delete this for being off topic but real quick : Is great you asked talk to counselor, hopefully that helps, but if it doesn’t for some reason, just keep looking, keep trying other things. If you keep looking and just keep trying to fix your issues (especially when things feel really horrible) eventually you’ll find the answers, you’ll feel better and you’ll have good/great mental health. Even if it takes awhile. There’s lots of totally free info/support online that can help so much :D

Comment: Hope mods don't delete but it would be completely understandable if they did. And yes, I haven't lost hope quite yet :) it's just frustrating as I'm happy (at least, not "sad") one day and the next day I'm down in the dumps. And so it goes, again and again.

You know sometimes I think this is the karmic result of me mentally dismissing so many stotras that claim to give intangible things like "peace of mind", "worldly happiness", etc. etc. I thought, "why would one explicitly pray for this?". And now, look at me, searching in vain for this very object :)

Comment: one perspective, sadness is there then only we can value happiness.

Comment: I understand, I made same mistake in spiritual matters & psychological matters, being dismissive, writing things off, thinking I knew everything (um no, so ridiculous over confidence hubris idiotic. Just embarrassing.) Then years later finally began to understand what was up. Ok friend your account is new & mine is 24 days old so I end our comments discussion here so I don’t get both of us deleted for being off-topic :D One last thing : yoga & meditation also helped me in a huge huge way. Enormously tremendously helpful, if you can try both those along with modern western psych help. Ttyl :D

Comment: Will do! Maybe for a reason, I stumbled upon authentic translations on how to practice yoga and pranayama very recently. I know you wanted to end this discussion, but I just wanted to let you know that this interaction with you has given me a measure of comfort. My ishta devata is Chandika devi (of the Devi Mahatmya), and maybe your username is just a co-incidence, but I'll choose to view it as a small pat on the back from above :)

Comment: @NikhilIyer Remember a simple line, "Hamare sath Shree Chandi maat toh kis baat ki chinta, charan me rakh diya jab maat toh kis baat ki chinta". Keep a deep faith in Bhagwati read Apaduddhar stotram with translation. Bhawani ashtakam will make ur faith unshakable. Bhagwati herself is cause of universe. Thus your dukha is by her will. Rejoice in it, because she has ur back. When Brahma cried to devi she manifested as Mahakali, for Shakra she became Mahishasurmardini for world she became Shakambhari. She nvr leave her devotees in pain. She's jaganmata. For more such read Adishankar's works.

Comment: @NikhilIyer In Tripura rahasya Dattatreya Bhagwan expalins purna Sharnagati. Where you must leave all pains and happiness in the feets of Bhagwati let her drive your life as she is Antaryami and Sarvajyanata the all knower. Trust her blindly, our only work is to serve her and sing her glories. So, chill leave depressions, for that organize utsavams of Bhagwati, go to her temples. Make garlands for her, grind chandan for her sing for her. That will give you hwr purna Anugraha.

Comment: Hello, bro try making friends who are spiritual and try to do therapy if you can afford it. Whenever you feel lonely, one should know that one is never alone and God is always with them. Also I would humbly suggest don't do yoga and pranayama on your own by reading books. Go to spiritual organisation and learn from a Guru.

Comment: @ChamundaDas and Hari Kumar thank youf or your kind words. I am indeed holding onto stotras like the Bhavani Ashtakam. I pray that one day by Her grace, there comes the time when I'm able to feel her Presence at all times, remain happy.

Comment: @NikhilIyer if you srsly ever feel lonely or get an urge to txt someone, u can Definetly reach me out on telegram. I hv got the same username there too. Feel free to text. Bhagwati's always there to help you. Remember Surath who was betrayed by his own Ministers in Saptashati, by the grace of Bhagwati not only won back his kingdom but also will become Manu in next Manavantara ! So, we just count on her grace. She's always there around us, but when we need her the most she will make us feel her presence❤️.

Comment: Thank you @Chamundadas; definitely means a lot.

Comment: @NikhilIyer Good to see other ppl reached out (and no one getting deleted :)) And even someone wrote a reply below too. Even slight mental health issues can seem too much at times, if so plz feel free @ comment on here, I just signed up WhatsApp & Telegram this past weekend and have those finally, also someone could make chat room on here if that would better to offer some advice. I think many ppl responding cause your post reaching out on here seemed quite sincere and so many ppl deal with these mental health obstacles in general and don’t say anything. Hang in there angel :D

Comment: @devibhakt definitely; it was very heartwarming to see all the support online here. Thanks for your wishes; hope you have a good day today :)

Answer (score 2):

*This may be a partial answer in the perspective of Bhagavad Gita*

It's imperative to understand  that no being(jiva) can ever remain (even for a split second) in inaction.(at the levels of Kayika,Vachika or Manasika),Hence , inevitably has a  seeking to engage with the world,(/other beings) that suits ones own nature .

**Bhagavad Gita 3.5**

> न हि कश्चित्क्षणमपि जातु तिष्ठत्यकर्मकृत् |
> कार्यते ह्यवश: कर्म सर्व: प्रकृतिजैर्गुणै:
>
> There is no one who can remain without action even for a moment. Indeed, all beings are compelled to act by their qualities born of material nature (the three guṇas).

***Who can be lonely***

Atma-Santhushtaha ,   (self realised)  is one could discover the bliss of ones own true essence  (Satchitananda), without any dependency over sensory integration.

*Bhagavad Gita 3.18*

> नैव तस्य कृतेनार्थो नाकृतेनेह कश्चन |
> न चास्य सर्वभूतेषु कश्चिदर्थव्यपाश्रय:
> They have nothing to gain or lose either in discharging or renouncing their duties. Nor do they need to depend on other living beings to fulfill their self-interest.

As  performing karma is  inevitable for anyone. (BG 3.8) suggests *action is superior to inaction* . One may find the means to engage in any dharmic action that suits their temperment and avoid remaining lonely.